# Request constraint check in google-bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery now allows unenforced primary key and foreign key constraints
I would like to be able to manually launch a consistency check of all of these constraints.

Is there anything available to do this?

I wrote a stored procedure that can do this for single column primary key and single column foreign key constraints by looking at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`... but I am not really happy with my solution... as it might break if the query optimizer gets more sophisticated.

I am hoping that there might be a more general tool for this.

Thanks,

Comment: Currently not in BigQuery but you can use additional data quality checks using tools like dbt, great expectations, bruin, etc to do that.